# Why is the ternary operator in python if else and not if then else?

Tags: python, if-statement, history, ternary

Code like this looks strange,

```
x = 1 if condition else 5
```

Most Programmers are accustomed to the pattern `<condition>` : `<on-true>` : `<on-false>`. Why does python break this well known and established pattern with its ternary operator? Why not something like this:

```
x = if condition then 1 else 5
```

Was there a reason for this design descision?

Comment: See http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/

Comment: Because `then` is not necessary to tell, what you want. Not all languages are using `then`, e.g. `Lisp`.

Comment: And from [Guido's pronouncement](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html): *Flames, pleas to reconsider, etc., to /dev/null* and most of all **It's still my language! :-)**.

Comment: Could someone explain why my question gets downvoted?

Answer (score 4):

Python is more English like, so it should be read like this

```
one, if condition is Truthy, else 5
```

Read more about this in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308-conditional-expressions)

Also, read this [PEP 308](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/), written by the BDFL himself.

Quoting from the [BDFL's pronouncement mail](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html),

> After a long discussion I've decided to add a shortcut conditional
>   expression to Python 2.5.
>
> The syntax will be
>
> ```
> A if C else B
> ```
>
> This first evaluates C; if it is true, A is evaluated to give the
>   result, otherwise, B is evaluated to give the result.
>
> The priorities will be such that you can write
>
> ```
> x = A if C else B
> x = lambda: A if C else B
> x = A if C else B if D else E
> ```
>
> But you'd have to write
>
> ```
> if (A if C else B):
> [x for x in seq if (A if C else B)]
> A if (X if C else Y) else B
> (A if C else B) if D else E
> ```
>
> Note that all these are intentionally ugly. :)
>
> In general, 'if' and 'else' bind less tight than everything except
>   lambda.
>
> We will adjust the syntax of what goes inside an 'if' to disallow
>   lambda; currently
>
> ```
> if lambda: x:
> ```
>
> is accepted but quite useless (it's always true) so this will be
>   disallowed.
>
> Flames, pleas to reconsider, etc., to /dev/null.
>
> Congratulations gracefully accepted.
>
> It's still my language! :-)

Comment: Downvoters, please please please let me know what is wrong with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The *reason* can be summarised as **because [Guido said so](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056846.html)**:

> The syntax will be
>
> ```
>    A if C else B
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> Flames, pleas to reconsider, etc., to /dev/null.
>
> Congratulations gracefully accepted.
>
> It's still my language! :-)

He cut the [Gordian knot that is PEP 308](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/); each variation had their supporters and detractors, and [it was his personal preference](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056546.html) that he picked here.

Python is not C, it is Python, and it is Guido's Python.

Personally, I agree with the pick, btw. I like the syntax.

Comment: @SundarNataraj: Because competition is healthy. I have my view on what makes a good answer here, thefourtheye has his. I do note that he has adjusted his answer since I posted my comments and my answer though.

Comment: u guys rocks .i am amzed by ur love on python :)